# JavaScript - Pagination with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, pagination

So I have made a kind of pagination with Javascript. First it gets JSON data from the file and puts it into array. Then it renders items to page. I have added there Previous and Next page buttons, but at the moment it works like if you click next page it just clears the `div` where are all the items and adds new ones, but my question is. How could I do it differently, so it would not clear out the div, because if I have chosen the item already and div is getting cleared, then the item will be `unchosen`.

Here's JSON javascript:

```
$.getJSON("/Search.php", function(itemsList){
    if(itemsList.items){
        for(var i = 0;i < itemsList.items.length; i++){
            pruice = itemsList.items[i].price;
            prices[itemsList.items[i].name] = pruice;
            items[i] = {
                name: itemsList.items[i].name,
                img: itemsList.items[i].img,
                price: itemsList.items[i].price,
                color: itemsList.items[i].color
            };
        }
    }
items.sort(function(a, b) {return b.price - a.price;});
OnFinished();
});
```

Render function

```
function OnFinished(){
$('#InventoryMe').empty();
var perPage = 30;
function paginate(items, page) {
    var start = perPage * page;
    return items.slice(start, start + perPage);
}

function renderItems(pageItems){
    pageItems.forEach(function(item, index, arr){
        $('#InventoryMe').append("<div class='item' style='background-image: url(https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/"+item.img+"/116x116f)'> <span class='nameArea'>"+item.name+"</span><span class='priceArea' style='border: 1px solid #1f1e1e;border-bottom-color:"+item.color+"'>"+item.price+"</span></div>");
    });
}
```

Next & Previous page

```
var page = 0;
renderItems(paginate(items, page));
$('#nextPage').on('click', function(){
    $('#InventoryMe').empty();
        page++;
        renderItems(paginate(items, page));
});
$('#previousPage').on('click', function(){
    $('#InventoryMe').empty();
        page--;
        renderItems(paginate(items, page));
});
}
```

Item selecting script

```
$( "#InventoryMe" ).on("click", ".item", function() {
    var calculateP = fee / 100;
    var itemName = $(this).find('.nameArea').text();
    var itemPrice = $(this).find('.priceArea').text();
    var newPrice = itemPrice * calculateP;
    var jacobExe = parseInt(newPrice * 100)/100;
    if($(this).closest(".item").hasClass("item-selected")){
        $(this).last().removeClass("item-selected");
    } else{
        $(this).toggleClass("item-selected");
    }
    calculateTotal();
});
```

Comment: If i understand correct you need to keep chosen items?

Comment: @Sabik, basically yes.

Comment: I added code for my item selecting.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are selecting an item, and paginate away and back again, and the selection is then gone.

If that is the case, I would save the selection in a javascript variable, preferably by id.

```
$.getJSON("/Search.php", function(itemsList){
    if(itemsList.items){
        for(var i = 0;i < itemsList.items.length; i++){
            pruice = itemsList.items[i].price;
            prices[itemsList.items[i].name] = pruice;
            items[i] = {
                name: itemsList.items[i].name,
                img: itemsList.items[i].img,
                price: itemsList.items[i].price,
                color: itemsList.items[i].color,
                id: itemsList.items[i].id //add id
            };
        }
    }
    items.sort(function(a, b) {return b.price - a.price;});
    OnFinished();
});
```

Add id to DOM

```
function renderItems(pageItems){
    pageItems.forEach(function(item, index, arr){
        $('#InventoryMe').append("<div data-id='"+item.id+"' class='item' style='background-image: url(https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/"+item.img+"/116x116f)'> <span class='nameArea'>"+item.name+"</span><span class='priceArea' style='border: 1px solid #1f1e1e;border-bottom-color:"+item.color+"'>"+item.price+"</span></div>");
    });
}
```

Then save id on click

```
var savedSelection;
$("#InventoryMe .item").click(function() {
    savedSelection = $(this).data('id');
    var calculateP = fee / 100;
    var itemName = $(this).find('.nameArea').text();
    var itemPrice = $(this).find('.priceArea').text();
    var newPrice = itemPrice * calculateP;
    var jacobExe = parseInt(newPrice * 100)/100;
    if($(this).closest(".item").hasClass("item-selected")){
        $(this).last().removeClass("item-selected");
    } else{
        $(this).toggleClass("item-selected");
    }
    calculateTotal();
});
```

Then in your renderItems, I would do

```
function renderItems(pageItems) {
    pageItems.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
        $('#InventoryMe').append("<div class='item' style='background-image: url(https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/"+item.img+"/116x116f)'> <span class='nameArea'>"+item.name+"</span><span class='priceArea' style='border: 1px solid #1f1e1e;border-bottom-color:"+item.color+"'>"+item.price+"</span></div>");
    });
    if (savedSelection) {
        $('[data-id="'+savedSelection+'"]').click();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to place savedSelection in a reachable scope of both functions.